# Получение имен компьютеров в приложении

Tags: сеть, windows, c++

Какой API в Windows позволяет в приложении на C++ получить список всех компьютеров рабочей группы?

Answer (score 2):

Нужна [работа с сетью](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385406.aspx) в Windows. Пример использования можно подсмотреть [здесь](http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1722&lngWId=3).

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно работать с сетью из приложения, есть варианты:

- [Network Management Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370675(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [System.Net Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145039.aspx)
- [WMI Tasks: Networking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394595(v=vs.85).aspx)